# grep or ripgrep: How to find only files that match multiple patterns (not only on the same line)?

Tags: grep, ripgrep

I'm searching for a fast method to find all files in a folder which contain 2 or more patterns

`grep -l -e foo -e bar ./*`
or
`rg -l -e foo -e bar`

show all files containing 'foo' AND 'bar' in the same line or 'foo' OR 'bar' in different lines but I want only files that have at a minimum one 'foo' match AND one 'bar' match in different lines. Files which only have 'foo' matches or only 'bar' matches shall be filtered out.

I know I could chain the grep calls but this will be too slow.

Answer (score 13):

So this doesn't perfectly answer the question, but, this is the StackOverflow question that pops up every time I google "ripgrep multiple patterns". So I'm leaving my answer here for the future googler (including myself)...

I primarily work in PowerShell, so this is how I perform an `and` search in ripgrep in PowerShell. This will match same line matches, which is why it's not a perfect answer, but it will identify files that match both patterns, and runs relatively quickly:

```
rg -l 'SecondSearchPattern' (rg -l 'FirstSearchPattern')
```

Explanation:

- First the parens run: `rg -l 'FirstSearchPattern'`, which searches all files for the pattern `FirstSearchPattern`. By using `-l` it returns a list of file paths only.
- By placing it in `(`parentheses`)`, it runs the whole command first, then "splats" the results of the command into the external `rg` command.
- The external `rg` command is now run like this:

  `rg -l 'SecondSearchPattern' "file.txt" "directory\file.txt"`

  And yes, it does put them into quotes, so it handles paths with spaces. This searches all provided files that match the pattern `SecondSearchPattern`. Thus returning only files that match both patterns.

You can go one step further and add on `| Get-Item` (`| gi`) to return filesystem objects, and `| % FullName` to get the full path.

```
rg -l 'SecondSearchPattern' (rg -l 'FirstSearchPattern') | gi | % FullName
```

Comment: Works also with bash `rg -l 'SecondSearchPattern' $(rg -l 'FirstSearchPattern')`

Answer (score 9):

`rg` with `multiline` does work, however it will print as result everything in-between the criteria and sometimes that's not useful.

For the use case of chaining searches (in e.g. `html, json`, etc), where the 1st criterium is just to narrow down the files, and the 2nd criterium is actually what I am looking for, this is a possible solution:

```
rg -0 -l crit1 | xargs -0 -I % rg -H crit2 %
```

Alternatively I have just discovered `ugrep` which supports combining multiple criteria using boolean operators both on *line* and *file* level. This is quite something. It's a bit slower than `rg + xargs`, however it prints nicely all lines matching all criteria from the files (instead of just showing the last criteria from above):

```
ugrep --files -e crit1 --and -e crit2
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to search for two or more words that occur on multiple lines you can use `ripgrep`'s option `--multiline-dotall`, in addition to to provide `-U`/`--multiline`. You also need to search for `foo` before `bar` and `bar` before `foo` using the `|` operator:

```
rg -lU --multiline-dotall 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo' .
```

For any number of words you'll need to `|` all permutations of those words. For that I use a small python script (which I called `rga`) which searches in
the current directory (and downwards), for files that contain all arguments given on the commandline:

```
#! /opt/util/py310/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess
from itertools import permutations

rgarg = '|'.join(('.*'.join(x) for x in permutations(sys.argv[1:])))
cmd = ['rg', '-lU', '--multiline-dotall', rgarg, '.']
# print(' '.join(cmd))
proc = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)
sys.stdout.write(proc.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

I have searched successfully with six arguments, above that the commandline becomes to long. There are probably ways around that by saving the argument to a file and adding `-f file_name`, but I never needed/investigated that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat f1
afoot
2bar
$ cat f2
foo bar
$ cat f3
foot
$ cat f4
bar
$ cat f5
barred
123
foo3

$ rg -Ul '(?s)foo.*?\n.*?bar|bar.*?\n.*?foo'
f5
f1
```

You can use `-U` option to match across lines. The `s` flag will enable `.` to match newlines as well. Since you want the matches to be across different lines, you need to match a newline character in between the search terms as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the following function: (tested in zsh)

```bash
multisearch() {
  case $# in
    0) return 1 ;;
    1) rg $1 ;;
  esac

  local lastArg=${@[${#}]}
  local files=(`rg --files-with-matches ${1}`)

  (( ${#files} )) || return 0

  # skip first and last arg
  for arg in ${@:2:# - 2}; do
    files=(`rg --files-with-matches ${arg} ${files[@]}`)

    (( ${#files} )) || return 0
  done

  rg ${lastArg} ${files[@]}
}
```

and use like:

```
$ multisearch foo bar
```